# facebook connect and disconnect

Tags: facebook

im using this code to create a facebook connect button on my site:

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMQTQ2DshKBkNG4aAZDZD',
                appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
                channelUrl : '//www.xxx.net/channel.html', // Channel File
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
              });
              // Additional initialization code here
            };

            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function(d){
               var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
               if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
               js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
               js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
               ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
             }(document));
             function logOut(){
                FB.logout();
             }
          </script>
          <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
          <a href="#" onclick="logOut();" >Logout</a>
```

when i hit the login button , im loggin in but when i hit the logout link
i get disconnected from facebook (not from the app itself)

and then when i do the following:
1. log in again (directly on facebook.com )
2. go to my site 
3. hit the login , and it sais im alread connected to the app

what am i doing wring here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are expecting to get disconnected from the app as well? That is not how it works. When you authorize an app, it will stay authorized unless you remove it from the authorized list in FB. Logging out will only log you out of FB.

When you login to FB, as your app is authorized already, hitting the login button goes to FB sees that its already authorized, tells you so.

Comment: then how can i create a logout function that will logout from the app alone (and leave the facebook connection intact) ? as i understand i should somehow deauthorize the app ?

Comment: @liorr i am confused on what exactly are you trying to do. When you say 'app' does that mean your website or the FB app you created to create the connection between your site and FB? FB connect is supposed to work the way it is now, the idea is to make it easy for people to login/connect to your site if they have FB. So if you de-authorize the app each time, its not much of a convenience if they have to authorize/allow the app each time.

Comment: ok , let me make it clear, the login button is for my web site of corse, but for that to happen the actual connection is created to my facebook app (right?) , then in order to logout from my site i will need the user to disconnect from the facebook app (right?) - so my question is how can i do that .. or am i getting it completely wrong ?

Comment: @liorr think of it this way. If the FB user went to three sites and connected them with FB, each time they logged into FB they have logged into those 3 sites as well because they have authorized the FB apps to make that connection. So after logging into FB , when they will go to those sites, they wont have to login again. This is perfectly normal. You don't have to disconnect them from your FB app at logout, this is the intended functionality of the Facebook connect mechanism, don't worry about it.

Comment: ok , so once i use facebook connect im logged in "for life" ? :-)

Comment: i mean as long as im logged in to facebook im logged in to all the sites i authorized

Comment: exactly! There is a section in FB > Privacy settings, which allows the users to de-authorize websites/apps

Comment: well thats make i more clear now ... Thanks ... you got a green V

Comment: _“then how can i create a logout function that will logout from the app alone (and leave the facebook connection intact) ?”_ – you are __required__ to provide a possibility to log out of your app __and__ Facebook as well by platform policies – https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ – see section _I. Features and Functionality, Point 6._

Comment: you mean i must allow users to log out completely from facebook right ? or is there a way to logout from my facebook app alone ?